# how to get data from html form and store it in a c# variable in ASP.Net MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to programming. I have basic understanding of Html, Css, C#, SQL queries, Entity Framework and ASP.Net-MVC. I'm trying to make a small time table test in ASP.Net-MVC.

The purpose of this application is to ask 10 questions, one question at a time and each time a question is attempted user will click on next button that will show next set of question. User need to attempt all 10 questions. Once reached it will tell show a message e.g. "Congratulations You have answered 7 questions From 10".

I want to know if it is possible to get data from html form and then store it in C# variable in ASP.Net MVC View. Below is what I have tried so far:

> Question View

```
@{ 
Random rnd = new Random();
int num1 = rnd.Next(13);
int num2 = rnd.Next(13);
int answer = num1 * num2;
int wrng1 = answer - 2;
int wrng2 = answer + 10;
int wrng3 = answer + 4;
int QAnswered = 0;
}

<div style="text-align:center;">
<h1>Questions Answered: @QAnswered</h1>

<!--Writes the Question-->
<h2 style="font-size: 150px; font-weight:900;">@num1 X @num2 = ?</h2>

<!--Buttons for Answers in form-->
<form action="/Home/CheckAnswer" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="UserAnswer" value="@answer" style="margin-right: 10px; width: 50px; height: 50px;" /><label style="color:white; font-size: 75px; width: 150px; height: 100px; border:1px solid black; background-color: cornflowerblue;">@answer</label>
    <input type="radio" name="UserAnswer" value="@wrng1" style="margin-right: 10px; width: 50px; height: 50px;" /><label style="color:white; font-size: 75px; width: 150px; height: 100px; border:1px solid black; background-color: cornflowerblue;">@wrng1</label>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <input type="radio" name="UserAnswer" value="@wrng2" style="margin-right: 10px; width: 50px; height: 50px;" /><label style="color:white; font-size: 75px; width: 150px; height: 100px; border:1px solid black; background-color: cornflowerblue;">@wrng2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="UserAnswer" value="@wrng3" style="margin-right: 10px; width: 50px; height: 50px;" /><label style="color:white; font-size: 75px; width: 150px; height: 100px; border:1px solid black; background-color: cornflowerblue;">@wrng3</label>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="CorrectAnswer" value="@answer" />
    <input type="hidden" name="QAnswered" value="@QAnswered" />
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Next" style="font-size: 50px; width: 150px; height: 75px;" />
</form>
```

and this is the code for the Actions in home controller:

```
public ActionResult Question()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckAnswer(int UserAnswer, int CorrectAnswer, int QAnswered)
    {   
        int TrueAnswers = 0;
        int FalseAnswers = 0;         
        //Check whether UserAnswer is true or false and increment values of them
        if (UserAnswer == CorrectAnswer)
        {
            TrueAnswers += 1;
            QAnswered += 1;
        }
        else if (UserAnswer != CorrectAnswer)
        {
            FalseAnswers += 1;
            QAnswered += 1;
        }

        if (QAnswered < 10)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Question");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

The thing is I don't want to make CheckAnswer action return content instead I want it to store the UserAnswer and check if it was correct then it will (somehow) store it as a true and vice versa and and after 10 questions (whether if it was right or wrong) I want it to display another View Which Will say something like "Congratulations you have answered 7 out of 10 questions correctly".

I don't know how will I do it so I hope anyone Will Help Me.

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("CongratulationsActionMethod");`

Comment: @Shyju thank you for replying but where should I `return RedirectToAction("CongratulationsActionMethod");` if you can explain it more simply so I can understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return Content(“...”)` is only to *return* TEXT-Plain FORMAT value

If you want to fire another action after form submit, you should enter `return RedirectToAction(“YOUR-ACTION”)`

---

**Update**

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Question()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int num1 = rnd.Next(13);
        int num2 = rnd.Next(13);
        return View(new QuestionViewModel
        {
            QuestionPart1 = num1,
            QuestionPart2 = num2,
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Question(QuestionViewModel model)
    {
        //Check whether UserAnswer is true or false and increment values of them
        if (model.UserAnswer == (model.QuestionPart1 * model.QuestionPart2))
        {
            if (Session["QAnswered"] == null)
                Session["QAnswered"] = 1;
            else
                Session["QAnswered"] = int.Parse(Session["QAnswered"].ToString()) + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Session["Failed"] == null)
                Session["Failed"] = 1;
            else
                Session["Failed"] = int.Parse(Session["Failed"].ToString()) + 1;
        }

        if (Session["QAnswered"] != null && int.Parse(Session["QAnswered"].ToString()) == 10)
        {
            // successful
            return RedirectToAction("Congratulation");
        }
        else
        {
            // failed
            return RedirectToAction("Question");
        }
    }
```

View:

```
    @model WebApplication2.Models.QuestionViewModel
    @{
        int answer = Model.QuestionPart1 * Model.QuestionPart2;
        int wrng1 = answer - 2;
        int wrng2 = answer + 10;
        int wrng3 = answer + 4;
        var answers = new List<int> { answer, wrng1, wrng2, wrng3 };
        Random rnd = new Random();
        answers = answers.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToList();
    }
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <h1>Questions Answered: @Session["QAnswered"]</h1>
    @if (int.Parse(Session["QAnswered"].ToString()) >= 7){
<text>
Congratulations, you've answered 7 of 10.
</text>
}
        <!--Writes the Question-->
        <h2 style="font-size: 150px; font-weight:900;">@Model.QuestionPart1 X @Model.QuestionPart2 = ?</h2>

        <!--Buttons for Answers in form-->
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Question", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
            {
                var choice = answers[index];
                <input type="radio" id="UserAnswer" name="UserAnswer" value="@choice" style="margin-right: 10px; width: 50px; height: 50px;" />
                <label style="color:white; font-size: 75px; width: 150px; height: 100px; border:1px solid black; background-color: cornflowerblue;">@choice</label>
                <br />

            }

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuestionPart2)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuestionPart1)
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Next" style="font-size: 50px; width: 150px; height: 75px;" />

        }
    </div>
```

Model:

```
public class QuestionViewModel
    {
        public int QuestionPart1 { get; set; }
        public int QuestionPart2 { get; set; }
        public int UserAnswer { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying but I know this already however if I change `return Content...` to `return RedirectToAction(...)` it will not take the variables stored in the controller and I want to store those variables so if you can help me more it will much more appreciated

Comment: @MohammadSherif where you want to store those variables, finally?

Comment: Now I can pass 3 variable data when posting the form, which is UserAnswer , correct answer, and the 3rd one is the questions answered(not in the code above also) so after passing these data to the home controller I can compare UserAnswer with CorrectAnswer And then increment the QAnswer By one, Here is the problem I'm facing right now if I run a breakpoint I will see that the data have came correctly and the incrementing process run succesfully I will say `if QuestionsAnswered < 10{return View(question)}` to get another question and when I do this Questions Answered will be zero again

Comment: @MohammadSherif look, i can’t find any clarification in your posted code. Please update question and show whole code you’ve been written.

Comment: I'm very sorry I did'nt recognize that I forgot to update my code but now it is updated I hope you can still help me, Thanks

Comment: @MohammadSherif i've updated my answer, works fine, check it out and enjoy and don't remember to LIKE

Comment: First, THANK YOU VERY MUCH for the help I can't believe you did all of this to me, but can you tell me where is the index action you wrote in the html form because now how will you receive the UserAnswer from the controller, again THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!

Comment: @MohammadSherif it doesn’t matter which action i wrote. I wrote a comment `successful` and `failed`, here you should do what you want. If success, go where you want.

Comment: @@ArashSh also does httpget send the information to the view?

Comment: yeah I saw that but I want to say in the last controller whether sucessful or failed I want it to redirect to the same controller (index) which will say "Congratulations you have correctly answered 7 from 10 questions " or something like that

Comment: @MohammadSherif httpget, initialize view for client, httppost, pass entered data to server

Comment: @@ArashSh Thanks again

Comment: @MohammadSherif i've updated answer again, check `View` , under _Question Answered: @Session["QAnswered"]_

Comment: First it gives an error at the comparison line `>=7` second you have misunderstand me I don't want 7 to be specific or even at the view I want it to just count the answers until I reach 10 questions then it will redirect me before that it will just say in a label "You have answered (number) from 10" and another thing it is not counting anything it will redirect me to another page(index) which I don't need until I reach 10 questions

Comment: @MohammadSherif  i got correct answer from the code, compare your entered code with mine

Comment: @@ArashSh did you answer 10 questions or only one?and how can we compare it I have just copy paste it change model name to mine and done