# What does @model int32 do in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I just want to know what does @model int32 do if we put it to the top of the view in asp.net mvc, can it pass data from controller to view? I'm asking this question because I saw someone uses it in another question without saying what it does and my reputation is not 50 because I'm new here so I just wanted to know.

Comment: It means the 'model' you pass to the view must be an `int` - e.g. in the controller method you would need to use `int model = 2; return View(model);` But it really makes not sense to be doing that, unless the 'view' is actually a custom `EditorTemplate`

Comment: @StephenMuecke When I first saw it people was saying you can either use it or use the viewbag is there any relation or something or can I pass more than 1 int at a time? Thank you again

Comment: You create a view model containing whatever properties you want, and pass that to the view as I explained in the [comments](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178257/discussion-on-question-by-mohammad-sherif-how-to-pass-variable-data-from-view-to) to your previous question

Comment: @StephenMuecke [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51908823/how-to-get-data-from-html-form-and-store-it-in-a-c-sharp-variable-in-asp-net-mvc/51913846?noredirect=1#comment90778643_51913846) This is the link to my updated question can you please check it out I have done many things toward my goal but I'm kinda stuck so if you can maybe check it and help me out it will be aswesome

Comment: You have ignored everything I told you! (and if you have any more comments add it to the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178257/discussion-on-question-by-mohammad-sherif-how-to-pass-variable-data-from-view-to)