# How to set string variable in C# Controller through an HTML text box input (in ASP.net MVC)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In this project I need to set the variable "string machineIP" as whatever the user inputs in the "IPlabel" text box by clicking the "callLogin".

## View "JCash.cshtml"

(I have removed non essencial parts of the code)

```
@page
@using MachineManager.Controllers
@model VNEViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "VNE JCash Manager";
}


<html>
<head>
    <title>JCash Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="JCash.cshtml" method="post" target="_blank">
        <div>
            <input id ="IPlabel"name="VNEIP" type="text" placeholder="IP da Máquina" />

            <button id="callLogin" type="button" onclick="Login()">Conectar</button>
```

## Controller "VMEcontroller.cs"

```
using MachineManager.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Reflection;


namespace MachineManager.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class VNEcontroller : Controller
    {
        public string machineIP = "192.168.10.107";
        public string url = "https://192.168.10.107/selfcashapi";

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SaveVariable(string VNEIP)
        {
            machineIP = VNEIP;
            return View();
        }
        

        public IActionResult SetIP(string VNEIP)
        {
            VNEViewModel JCashIP = new VNEViewModel();
            JCashIP.machineIP = VNEIP;

            machineIP = VNEIP;
            url = "https://" + machineIP + "/selfcashapi/";

            return View(new VNEViewModel { machineIP = this.machineIP, url = this.url});
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/Login")]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                object jsonObj = new
                {
                    tipo = 40
                };
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj);

                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            string result = "";
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(result);

            string req_status = jObject["req_status"]?.ToString();

            return View(req_status);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult EmptyHopper(bool totalEmpty = true)
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                object jsonObj = new
                {
                    tipo = 50,
                    full = totalEmpty ? 0 : 1
                };
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj);

                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            string result = "";
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        return View(result);
        }
    }
}
```

## Model "VNEViewModel"

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MachineManager.Models
{
    public class VNEViewModel
    {
        public string? machineIP { get; set; }
        public string? url { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I viewed a couple solutions, and I have seen [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51908823/how-to-get-data-from-html-form-and-store-it-in-a-c-sharp-variable-in-asp-net-mvc), which does seem like my exact question, but to be honest I don't really get it and the code is nothing like mine so I couldn't really adapt it.

Comment: onclick="Login()" will call a Javascript function called "Login()".  I think the form will still be submitted to JCash.cshtml though.  No idea what that's going to do without a controller or method associated with the form post.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reach the desired action in the controller? I mean, if you put a breakpoint in the action which has to store the variable, does the compiler hit that breakpoint? I don't think it will to be honest. You have to set the controller's action in the `<form>` element in the view like so:

```
<form action="Login" method="post" target="_blank">
```

And remove the attribute `onclick="Login()"` from the button. When the user click on a button of type 'submit', asp.net will automatically call the action that you specified in the form.

p.s. You can also specify the controller where the action belongs, for example:

```
<form action="Login" controller="MyController" method="post" target="_blank">
```